# How to assess predictive power of set of categorical predictors of a binary outcome? Calculate probabilities or logistic regression?

Tags: r, probability, logistic

I am trying to determine if simple probabilities will work for my problem or if it will be better to use (and learn about) more sophisticated methods like logistic regression.

The response variable in this problem is a binary response (0, 1).  I have a number of predictor variables that are all categorical and unordered.  I am trying to determine which combinations of the predictor variables yield the highest proportion of 1's.  Do I need logistic regression?  How would it be an advantage to just calculating proportions in my sample set for each combination of the categorical predictors?

Comment: If you have more than 1 predictor, it could be tricky to do this without some kind of regression model. What did you have in mind? Just a big $k$-dimensional contigency table ($k$ is the number of predictors)?

Comment: Are the predictor categories grouped into more than one factor, & if so are they crossed or nested? Also, are you only interested in making a descriptive statement? If your data are complex a LR model may be more convenient, & if you want to make inferences LR is strongly preferable, I think.

Comment: @Macro - Yes, I was thinking it would essentially be a big table, with one column showing # of sample points that correspond to the scenario, and another column showing the proportion of 1's.  I have five categorical predictors, each with 10-30 possible values, so I know the list of scenarios would be high.  I was thinking to script a loop in R that goes through each and output significant results (high proportion of 1's plus large # of sample points in the scenario).

Comment: @gung - The factors are only partially crossed.  None of the factors would be considered nested.  I'm interested in finding the combinations of factors (e.g. State, Customer, Employee) that will likely have a high probability of the response variable being equal to 1.

Comment: If you have 5 predictors, you won't be able to display the data in a rectangular table. If it were 3 predictors, you could display it in a cube; 4 predictors a list of cubes and so on :) As it is, you will have a 5 dimensional table, which could get tricky. The odds ratios that come out of a logistic regression are exactly the same as those you would get from doing a regular contigency table analysis, so what's the problem with regression?

Comment: @Macro - Right, a 5 dimensional table would be a bit unwieldy.  Even worse, I was thinking of creating a set of dummy variables for each categorical predictor and so I'd essentially have a matrix of 1's and 0's to indicate the predictor combination, and then two additional columns in the matrix that show me what I want:  the proportion of 1's in the response variable, plus some measure of confidence/fit for the scenario.  I'm new to statistics and regression analysis, but I will look into odds ratios/logistic regression.  It sounds like you think it will do the job.

Comment: @Rachel, are your categorical variables independent? As others pointed out, logistic regression assumes independent influence of the predictors. If you don't think they are independent, then I suggest that you use a method that doesn't have this assumption. See my answer below.

Comment: @EmreA - Unfortunately the categorical variables are not entirely independent.  Some combinations will be more likely than others...

Comment: Then, my suggestion seems to be a better fit to your problem than logistic regression. The method will give you the group of predictors which are maximally relevant with the response variable and minimally redundant in itself. Relevance and redundancy are defined based on mutual information. Check this faq: http://penglab.janelia.org/proj/mRMR/FAQ_mrmr.htm#Q1.1

Comment: penglab has moved: http://home.penglab.com/proj/mRMR/

Answer (score 11):

**Logistic regression will, up to numerical imprecision, give exactly the same fits as the tabulated percentages.**  Therefore, if your independent variables are *factor* objects `factor1`, etc., and the dependent results (0 and 1) are `x`, then you can obtain the effects with an expression like

```
aggregate(x, list(factor1, <etc>), FUN=mean)
```

Compare this to

```
glm(x ~ factor1 * <etc>, family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

---

**As an example,** let's generate some random data:

```
set.seed(17)
n <- 1000
x <- sample(c(0,1), n, replace=TRUE)
factor1 <- as.factor(floor(2*runif(n)))
factor2 <- as.factor(floor(3*runif(n)))
factor3 <- as.factor(floor(4*runif(n)))
```

**The summary** is obtained with

```
aggregate.results <- aggregate(x, list(factor1, factor2, factor3), FUN=mean)
aggregate.results
```

Its output includes

```
   Group.1 Group.2 Group.3         x
1        0       0       0 0.5128205
2        1       0       0 0.4210526
3        0       1       0 0.5454545
4        1       1       0 0.6071429
5        0       2       0 0.4736842
6        1       2       0 0.5000000
...
24       1       2       3 0.5227273
```

For future reference, the estimate for factors at levels (1,2,0) in row 6 of the output is 0.5.

**The logistic regression** gives up its coefficients this way:

```
model <- glm(x ~ factor1 * factor2 * factor3, family=binomial(link="logit"))
b <- model$coefficients
```

To use them, we need the logistic function:

```
logistic <- function(x) 1 / (1 + exp(-x))
```

To obtain, e.g., the estimate for factors at levels (1,2,0), compute

```
logistic (b["(Intercept)"] + b["factor11"] + b["factor22"] + b["factor11:factor22"])
```

(Notice how all interactions must be included in the model and all associated coefficients have to be applied to obtain a correct estimate.)
The output is

```
(Intercept) 
        0.5
```

agreeing with the results of `aggregate`.  (The "(Intercept)" heading in the output is a vestige of the input and effectively meaningless for this calculation.)

---

**The same information in yet another form appears in the output of `table`**. E.g., the (lengthy) output of

```
table(x, factor1, factor2, factor3)
```

includes this panel:

```
, , factor2 = 2, factor3 = 0

   factor1
x    0  1
  0 20 21
  1 18 21
```

The column for `factor1` = 1 corresponds to the three factors at levels (1,2,0) and shows that $21/(21+21) = 0.5$ of the values of `x` equal $1$, agreeing with what we read out of `aggregate` and `glm`.

---

Finally, **a combination of factors yielding the highest proportion *in the dataset*** is conveniently obtained from the output of `aggregate`:

```
> aggregate.results[which.max(aggregate.results$x),]
  Group.1 Group.2 Group.3         x
4       1       1       0 0.6071429
```

Comment: This is a lot of information and will take me some time for me to digest, but I'm glad to hear the tabulated percentages and logistic regressions will essentially give me the same results.  I ran the aggregate function on two of the predictors and it finished immediately...the results for the logistic fit has been running for a number of minutes and hasn't finished yet.  I'll continue to tweak things, but I may end up just using the tabulated percentages.  Thank you!

Comment: (+1), Off the cuff I wonder if standard errors *in this context* from the logistic regression can be incorporated into the graphical mosaic plot summaries I suggested. I also suspect this could be a good way to quickly "filter" the results for interesting interactions (these are just my musings though!)

Comment: "Logistic regression will, up to numerical imprecision, give exactly the same fits as the tabulated percentages":  Isn't she tabulating percentages for every configuration of predictors?  In which case, logistic regression can't encode all possible relationships.

Comment: @Neil Sure it can encode all the "relationships" (combinations of factors): use all possible interactions. See the R code for an example.  When the factors are numerous, there will in practice be many empty combinations, but decent software will have no problem dealing with that. Even better software will handle the combinations with no variation in responses.

Comment: @Andy I love your reply about the graphics--we need to find a way to create a thread where it's exactly the right answer! Perhaps your thought about incorporating error estimates into the mosaic plots would be the way to approach it: how would you represent the logistic estimates, the actual data, and/or the error simultaneously in them?

Comment: @whuber: My apologies, but I still haven't learned R.  Are you creating a factor for every combination of predictors?

Comment: @Neil Sorry about sounding R-centric! (I'm still learning it myself.) Yes, I am in effect creating a factor for every combination of predictors (or at least every combination that is represented in the dataset). This is done in the call to `glm` (the logistic regression procedure) by listing each of the individual factors and, by virtue of the `*` operator in the formula, requesting *all* $2$-way through $n$-way interactions. This is equivalent to creating a single new factor representing all possible combinations of the predictors and regressing against that factor.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks for the explanation!  Nice answer.

Answer (score 6):

For a **quick** glance at the proportion of binary responses within each category and/or conditional on multiple categories, graphical plots can be of service. In particular, to simultaneously visualize proportions conditioned on many categorical independent variables I would suggest *Mosaic Plots*.

Below is an example taken from a blog post, [Understanding area based plots: Mosaic plots](http://www.theusrus.de/blog/understanding-mosaic-plots/) from the *Statistical graphics and more* blog. This example visualizes the proportion of survivors on the Titanic in blue, conditional on the class of the passenger. One can simultaneously assess the proportion of survivors, while still appreciating the total number of passengers within each of the subgroups (useful information for sure, especially when certain sub-groups are sparse in number and we would expect more random variation).

[image: Mosaic plot of Titanic]
<sub>(source: [theusrus.de](http://www.theusrus.de/Blog-files/Mosaic1.png))</sub>

One can then make subsequent mosaic plots conditional on multiple categorical independent variables. The next example from the same blog post in a quick visual summary demonstrates that *all* children passengers in the first and second classes survived, while in the third class children did not fare nearly as well. It also clearly shows that female adults had a much higher survival rate compared to males within each class, although the proportion of female survivors between classes diminished appreciably from the first to second to third classes (and then was relatively high again for the crew, although again note not many female crew members exist, given how narrow the bar is).

[image: Mosaic conditional on third variable]
<sub>(source: [theusrus.de](http://www.theusrus.de/Blog-files/Mosaic2.png))</sub>

It is amazing how much information is displayed, this is proportions in *four* dimensions (Class, Adult/Child, Sex and Proportion of Survivors)!

I agree if you are interested in prediction or more causal explanation in general you will want to turn to more formal modelling. Graphical plots can be very quick visual clues though as to the nature of the data, and can provide other insights often missed when simply estimating regression models (especially when considering interactions between the different categorical variables).

Comment: +1, this is the point I was trying to make in my comment above regarding whether the goal was simple description or inference. Nb, that the point is clearer & better made w/ figures!

Comment: @gung thanks, what does `Nb` stand for? I always say better with figures as well!

Comment: Not anything related to statistics, "n.b." stands for *nota bene*, which in turn is Latin for 'note well' (literally), or 'note that' / 'notice' (more colloquially).

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your needs, you might find that recursive partioning provides an easy to interpret method for predicting an outcome variable. For an *R* introduction to these methods, see Quick-R's [Tree-based model](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cart.html) page. I generally favour `ctree()` implementation in R's `party package as one does not have to worry about pruning, and it produces pretty graphics by default.

This would fall into the category of feature selection algorithms suggested in a previous answer, and generally gives as good if not better predictions as logistic regression.

Answer (score 2):

Given your five categorical predictors with let's say 20 outcomes each, then the solution with a different prediction for each configuration of predictors needs $20^5$ parameters.  Each of those parameters needs many training examples in order to be learned well.  Do you have at least ten million training examples spread over all configurations?  If so, go ahead and do it that way.

If you have less data, you want to learn fewer parameters.  You can reduce the number of parameters by assuming, for example, that configurations of individual predictors have consistent effects on the response variable.

If you believe that your predictors are independent of each other, then logistic regression is the unique algorithm that does the right thing.  (Even if they're not independent, it can still do fairly well.)

In summary, logistic regression makes an assumption about independent influence of predictors, which reduces the number of model parameters, and yields a model that's easy to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at feature selection algorithms. One that is suitable for your case (binary classification, categorical variables) is the "minimum Redundancy Maximum Relevance" (mRMR) method. You can quickly try it online at http://penglab.janelia.org/proj/mRMR/

Comment: Is it possible to run this program with more than one categorical predictor?  On the upload page it looks like only the first column can be the "class" of data...  Perhaps I do not understand how the data is supposed to be formatted.

Comment: Or is the "class" supposed to be the output variable, in this case a 0 or 1?  If so, is it important to turn the categorical variables into dummy variables to show indicators for each?

Comment: You can have as many predictors as you want. The first row of your data file must be the feature names, and the first column must be the classes (response variable) for samples. So, an example is: 
`response,predictor1,predictor2,predictor3 <line break here> 1,5,4,3 <line break here> 0,5,3,-1 <line break here> 1,1,2,3`

Answer (score 1):

I work in the field of credit scoring, where what here is being presented as a strange case is the norm.

We use logistic regression, and convert both categorical and continuous variables into weights of evidence (WOEs), that are then used as the predictors in the regression.  A lot of time is spent grouping the categorical variables, and discretising (binning/classing) the continuous variables.

The weight of evidence is a simple calculation.  It is the log of the odds for the class, less the log of odds for the population:
WOE = ln(Good(Class)/Bad(Class)) - ln(Good(ALL)/Bad(ALL))
This is the standard transformation methodology for almost all credit scoring models built using logistic regression.  You can use the same numbers in a piecewise approach.

The beauty of it is that you will always know whether the coefficients being assigned to each WOE make sense.  Negative coefficients are contrary to the patterns within the data, and usually result from multicollinearity; and coefficients over 1.0 indicate overcompensation.  Most coefficients will come out somewhere between zero and one.

Comment: Thank you for an interesting and informative post.  I cannot figure out how it responds to the question in this thread, though.  What is the "strange case" to which you refer?  Did you perhaps intend to use this to reply to another question elsewhere?